# Just deployed wordpress site and now can't login to my backend

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-forge, envoyer.io

I have just deployed my wordpress site using forge and envoyer and now for some reason when I try and login to the backend it says my login credentials aren't accurate and it won't allow me to send an email to retrieve my login details.

This is what it looks like when i try an login. I know my details are correct because I have them written down and just copied and pasted. They work locally.

[image: invalid username]

and then when I try and put in an email it says this:

[image: the email could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function]
I am not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ask your hosting provider regarding the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

can you please clear your browser cookie and cache